# The availability of binutils on different linux distributions

Tags: distribution-choice, shared-library

I want to know if there is some sort of a list of applications available by default in different linux distributions, some kind of a standard list of binaries that all distributions have.

I specifically have `readelf` used for a program that I have created that will be used on different distributions. From what I know `readelf` is a part of `binutils`. Are `binutils` always shipped with all the linux distributions out there?

I am fairly new to this and I just want to be sure. I have only used `redhat` and `ubuntu` before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`binutils` is a pretty crucial part of any Linux distribution, so I'd say you're safe assuming that you will find it in any distribution.

Comment: Is that still true for non-x86 architectures, such as ARM?  How about Android?  AFAICT the OpenBSD folks have plenty of fun porting and updating `binutils` specifically to non-x86 architectures.

Comment: @SatoKatsura That's nice to point out. I forgot to mention though my application is to be used only on desktops.

Comment: @SatoKatsura it is true of typical Linux distributions on non-x86 architectures too; `binutils` is one of the first pieces you need in a GNU stack (a linker is pretty useful), and it supports a huge variety of architectures. I don't think Android has it by default but it is available there too.

Comment: @StephenKitt Then how about those architectures that don't use ELF (routers and such)?  Do they still have `readelf` compiled with `binutils`?

Comment: @SatoKatsura `binutils` supports more formats than just ELF. I wouldn't expect to find `binutils` *installed* on small devices (or even most Linux systems), but it is *available* for a huge variety of targets.

Comment: As far as `readelf` is concerned, I don't know, but I'd imagine it wouldn't make sense to run the OP's program on a platform which doesn't have it available...